# Parallel Spark Streaming Applications on YARN EMR

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I'm facing an issue while trying to run parallel Spark Streaming jobs on EMR. 
YARN is configured to use capacity scheduler and 3 queues A,B,C are configured.

1. I submit the first streaming `job A` into `queue A` and it runs fine.
2. After a couple of minutes , I submit the second `job B` into `queue B`.

As soon as I submit `job B`, `job A` stops running and EMR yarn console shows a spike in pending containers , and `job B` starts running fine.

Both the applications are submitted into the correct queues as expected and are running well within queues' capacity.

Here is my spark submit command.

```
spark-submit --name "A" \
    --master yarn \
    --queue A \
    --deploy-mode client \
    --executor-cores 2 \
    --driver-memory 2G \
    --executor-memory 1G \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=2 \
    --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=1 \
    --conf spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion=false 
    --class test test.jar
```

The spark streaming query progress keeps updating even after job A is stuck :

> {"Event":"org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryListener$QueryProgressEvent",
>       "progress":{"id":"047d9837-c493-4adf-b8ff-c916ed67461f","runId":"f02114ce-30a3-4678-bb48-a32b68d853be","name":null,"timestamp":"2019-10-26T07:03:08.382Z","batchId":184,"durationMs":{"triggerExecution":0,"getOffset":0},
>       "eventTime":{},"stateOperators":[],
>       "sources":[{"description":"MQTTStreamSource[brokerUrl: tcp://mqtt-tap.com:1883, topic: monitor/tenant/+ 
>       clientId: stage]","startOffset":"182","endOffset":"182","numInputRows":0,"inputRowsPerSecond":0.0,"processedRowsPerSecond":"NaN"}],
>       "sink":{"description":"ForeachSink"}}}

Both the jobs are able to run fine on local mode. I've checked the node manager logs and could not find any errors.  And the issue occurs only on yarn client/cluster mode. Please suggest how to debug this issue.

Edit : Added the scheduler settings.

```
<!--
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License. See accompanying LICENSE file.
-->
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-applications</name>
    <value>10000</value>
    <description>
      Maximum number of applications that can be pending and running.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
    <value>0.5</value>
    <description>
      Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run 
      application masters i.e. controls number of concurrent running
      applications.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DefaultResourceCalculator</value>
    <description>
      The ResourceCalculator implementation to be used to compare 
      Resources in the scheduler.
      The default i.e. DefaultResourceCalculator only uses Memory while
      DominantResourceCalculator uses dominant-resource to compare 
      multi-dimensional resources such as Memory, CPU etc.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.queues</name>
    <value>alpha,beta,default</value>
    <description>
      The queues at the this level (root is the root queue).
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.alpha.capacity</name>
    <value>50</value>
    <description>Default queue target capacity.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.beta.capacity</name>
    <value>30</value>
    <description>Default queue target capacity.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.capacity</name>
    <value>20</value>
    <description>Default queue target capacity.</description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.user-limit-factor</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
      Default queue user limit a percentage from 0.0 to 1.0.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.alpha.user-limit-factor</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
      Default queue user limit a percentage from 0.0 to 1.0.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.beta.user-limit-factor</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
      Default queue user limit a percentage from 0.0 to 1.0.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>20</value>
    <description>
      The maximum capacity of the default queue. 
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.alpha.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>50</value>
    <description>
      The maximum capacity of the default queue. 
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.beta.maximum-capacity</name>
    <value>30</value>
    <description>
      The maximum capacity of the default queue. 
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
    <description>
      The state of the default queue. State can be one of RUNNING or STOPPED.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.alpha.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
    <description>
      The state of the default queue. State can be one of RUNNING or STOPPED.
    </description>
  </property>

    <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.beta.state</name>
    <value>RUNNING</value>
    <description>
      The state of the default queue. State can be one of RUNNING or STOPPED.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_submit_applications</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can submit jobs to the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.acl_administer_queue</name>
    <value>*</value>
    <description>
      The ACL of who can administer jobs on the default queue.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.node-locality-delay</name>
    <value>40</value>
    <description>
      Number of missed scheduling opportunities after which the CapacityScheduler 
      attempts to schedule rack-local containers. 
      Typically this should be set to number of nodes in the cluster, By default is setting 
      approximately number of nodes in one rack which is 40.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings</name>
    <value></value>
    <description>
      A list of mappings that will be used to assign jobs to queues
      The syntax for this list is [u|g]:[name]:[queue_name][,next mapping]*
      Typically this list will be used to map users to queues,
      for example, u:%user:%user maps all users to queues with the same name
      as the user.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.queue-mappings-override.enable</name>
    <value>false</value>
    <description>
      If a queue mapping is present, will it override the value specified
      by the user? This can be used by administrators to place jobs in queues
      that are different than the one specified by the user.
      The default is false.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.per-node-heartbeat.maximum-offswitch-assignments</name>
    <value>1</value>
    <description>
      Controls the number of OFF_SWITCH assignments allowed
      during a node's heartbeat. Increasing this value can improve
      scheduling rate for OFF_SWITCH containers. Lower values reduce
      "clumping" of applications on particular nodes. The default is 1.
      Legal values are 1-MAX_INT. This config is refreshable.
    </description>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.accessible-node-labels.CORE.capacity</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.accessible-node-labels</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.accessible-node-labels.CORE.capacity</name>
    <value>20</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.alpha.accessible-node-labels.CORE.capacity</name>
    <value>50</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.beta.accessible-node-labels.CORE.capacity</name>
    <value>30</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

Comment: On EMR, would not think a use case for EMR as I was told

Comment: Show the yarn queue settings. Your second queue may not limited to the resource usage.

Comment: @Lamanus added the yarn queue settings , I'm running the jobs on alpha and beta queues,

Comment: @thebluephantom Sorry , I did not understand your comment. My use case is to run two parallel streaming applications which consume data from two different kinds of hardwares.

Comment: Well EMR is emant for short living clusters in the real world, AWS AMAZON told me on a PoC